# Calculating ${\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\omega x)}{x^{2} + 25}\,{\rm d}x}$ using contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

I want to calculate
$\displaystyle{
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\left(\omega x\right)}{x^{2} + 25}\,{\rm d}x\,,
\quad}$ for $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$

I thought of integrating along the line segment $\left[-R, R\right]$ and the semicircle $C = \left\{z: \left\vert z\right\vert = R, \; \Im z\geq 0\right\}$. In my book this is said to be a wrong method, but I don't understand why ( I even get the same result ).

Can someone explain me why this is wrong, and how it should be done instead?

Comment: Hint:  You will need to integrate around two semi-circles that correspond to each of the poles at $x=\pm 5i$ and then calculate the appropriate residues.  One may use a symmetry of the integrand as well to simplify the problem.

Comment: @Riemann1337 The poles are at $z=\pm 5i$. And I think that this is the same as what I did (which is wrong).

Comment: @user102815 Emulate what was done [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479442/calculate-the-value-of-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-cos-3xx2a).

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The result doesn't change if you write, in the integrand, $\large\left\vert \omega\right\vert$ instead of $\large\omega$ since the $\large\cos$ function is even. You can concentrate in just one case ( one semicircle ).

Comment: @Lord_Farin I was the one who edit ( no the OP ) and insert the $\tt\mbox{\displaystyle{}}$. I didn't know about the policy you mention above. Thanks. I'll be aware of that in the future.

Comment: @user102815 You should also check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272622/integral-evaluation-int-infty-infty-frac-cos-ax-pi-1x2dx?rq=1).

Comment: @GitGud Isn't there something I can do with the Fourier transform? The integral is the real part of the Fourier transform of {\frac{1}{x^2+25}}) $

Comment: @user102815 In both links there are answers that use the [Fourier Transform](http://www.geeksaresexy.net/2013/02/17/the-fourier-transform-pic/).

Comment: @GitGud Can you tell me what is fundamentally wrong with what I proposed in the main question?

Comment: @user102815 I apologize, I hadn't even read your question. I just saw the integral. What you did was done in both links I provided, there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: What you need to do is replace the cosine by an exponential. The cosine grows exponentially for $\lvert\operatorname{Im} z\rvert \to\infty$, so you can't conclude that the integral over the semicircle vanishes in the limit by the standard arguments. If you replace the cosine with $e^{i\omega x}$, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272622/integral-evaluation-int-infty-infty-frac-cos-ax-pi-1x2dx?rq=1) the integral is solved by a few methods. One of them is by [user17762](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/17762/user17762) who set a differential equation for $\ds{{\rm I}\pars{\omega} \equiv \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{\omega x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x}$. Namely,
${\rm I}''\pars{\omega} - 25\,{\rm I}\pars{\omega} = -2\pi\,\delta\pars{\omega}$.
The equation in the above mentioned question is slightly different due to a different parameters but both cases are similar after a suitable scaling. The above mentioned user solves the equation without the $-2\delta\pars{\omega}$ term and later use some arguments to arrive to the correct solution. One comment ( by [Ron Gordon](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/53268/ron-gordon) ) pointed out the existence of the Dirac delta term in the right hand side which indicates that ${\rm I}\pars{\omega}$ is a Green function. Here we'll solve the above mentioned differential equation by taking explicitly into account the Dirac delta term.

> The solutions of ${\rm I}''\pars{\omega} - {\rm I}\pars{\omega} = 0$ are lineal combination of $\expo{-5\omega}$ and $\expo{5\omega}$. The solution is written as
> $$
> {\rm I}\pars{\omega}
> =
> \Theta\pars{-5\omega}\pars{A\expo{-5\omega} + B\expo{5\omega}}
> +
> \Theta\pars{\omega}\pars{C\expo{-5\omega} + D\expo{5\omega}}
> $$
> where $A, B, C$ and $D$ are constants ( independent de $\omega$ ). The solution is an even function of $\omega$ which requires $A = D$ and $B = C$. That condition reduces ${\rm I}\pars{\omega}$ to:
> \begin{align}
> {\rm I}\pars{\omega}
> &=
> \Theta\pars{-\omega}\pars{A\expo{5\verts{\omega}} + B\expo{-5\verts{\omega}}}
> +
> \Theta\pars{\omega}\pars{B\expo{-5\verts{\omega}} + A\expo{5\verts{\omega}}}
> =
> A\expo{5\verts{\omega}} + B\expo{-5\verts{\omega}}
> \end{align}
> The boundary condition ${\rm I}\pars{0} = \pi/5$ leads to $A + B = \pi/5$. Then,
> $$
> {\rm I}\pars{\omega} = 2A\sinh\pars{5\verts{\omega}}
> +
> {1 \over 5}\,\pi\expo{-5\verts{\omega}}
> \quad\mbox{and}\quad
> {\rm I}'\pars{\omega}
> =
> 5\bracks{2A\cosh\pars{5\verts{\omega}}
> -
> {1 \over 5}\,\pi\expo{-5\verts{\omega}}}\sgn\pars{\omega}
> $$
> The differential equation leads to the condition
> $$
> \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}
> \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}{\rm I}''\pars{\omega}\,\dd\omega = -2\pi
> \quad\imp\quad
> \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}
> \bracks{{\rm I}'\pars{\epsilon} - {\rm I}'\pars{-\epsilon}} = -2\pi
> $$
> $$
> -2\pi = 5\pars{2A - {\pi \over 5}} - 5\pars{-2A + {\pi \over 5}}
> =
> 20A - 2\,\pi\
> \imp\
> A = 0\
> \imp\
> {\rm I}\pars{\omega} = {1 \over5}\,\pi\expo{-5\verts{\omega}}
> $$

Then
$${\large
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{\omega x} \over x^{2} + 25}\,\dd x
=
{1 \over5}\,\pi\expo{-5\verts{\omega}}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the fact that the cosine blows up along a semicircle in the upper or lower half plane.  To do this correctly, you can break the cosine into complex exponentials, each of which satisfies Jordan's lemma on one or the other semicircular contour, as I demonstrate below.

Because cosine is even, we may assume that $\omega > 0$.  Rewrite the integral as

$$\frac12 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{i \omega x} + e^{-i \omega x}}{x^2+25} $$

Break the integral in two.  Now first consider the following contour integral

$$\oint_{C_+} dz \frac{e^{i \omega z}}{z^2+25} $$

where $C_+$ is a semicircle of radius $R$ in the upper half-plane.  The contour integral is equal to

$$\int_{-R}^R dx \frac{e^{i \omega x}}{x^2+25} + i R \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{e^{-\omega R \sin{\theta}} e^{i \omega R \cos{\theta}}}{R^2 e^{i 2 \theta}+25} $$

As $R \to \infty$ the second integral has a magnitude bounded from above by

$$\frac{2}{R} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-\omega R \sin{\theta}} \le \frac{2}{R} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-2 \omega R \theta/\pi} \le \frac{\pi}{2 \omega R^2} $$

Thus the second integral vanishes as $R \to \infty$.  By the residue theorem, the contour integral is also equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the residue at the pole $z=5 i$.  Therefore,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{i \omega x}}{x^2+25} = i 2 \pi \frac{e^{i \omega (5 i)}}{2 \cdot 5 i} = \frac{\pi}{5} e^{-5 \omega}$$

Now consider the following contour integral:

$$\oint_{C_-} dz \frac{e^{-i \omega z}}{z^2+25} $$

where $C_-$ is a semicircle of radius $R$ in the lower half-plane.  The contour integral is equal to

$$\int_{R}^{-R} dx \frac{e^{-i \omega x}}{x^2+25} + i R \int_{\pi}^{2 \pi} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{e^{\omega R \sin{\theta}} e^{-i \omega R \cos{\theta}}}{R^2 e^{i 2 \theta}+25} $$

Note that $\sin{(\pi+\theta)}=-\sin{\theta}$.  As $R \to \infty$ the second integral has a magnitude bounded from above by

$$\frac{2}{R} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-\omega R \sin{\theta}} \le \frac{2}{R} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-2 \omega R \theta/\pi} \le \frac{\pi}{2 \omega R^2} $$

Thus the second integral vanishes as $R \to \infty$.  By the residue theorem, the contour integral is also equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the residue at the pole $z=-5 i$.  Therefore,

$$-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{i \omega x}}{x^2+25} = i 2 \pi \frac{e^{-i \omega (-5 i)}}{2 \cdot (-5 i)} = -\frac{\pi}{5} e^{-5 \omega}$$

Therefore, putting this all together, and considering the fact that the integrand is even with respect to $\omega$, we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{\cos{\omega x}}{x^2+25} =\frac{\pi}{5} e^{-5 |\omega|}$$